# WordPress as a web service only

Tags: web-services

TL;DR
Prevent all access to site apart from admin panel (dashboard) and custom rest API endpoints.

I would like to create a web service using WordPress rest api.
I want to give access only to my custom endpoints and nothing else, all default WordPress endpoints should always return 403.
Frontend doesn't exist for this webs ervice, so maybe aprat from the home page (or even that) no other urls would be available.

Admin panel(dashboard) would be ideally limitid to my USER_AGENT and IP, but if thats not possible I can live with it.

The concept is to only have my custom endpoints with rest API and nothing else.

No need for any plugins/themes, core updates and all that. just a web service using WordPress CMS.

Comment: There's a few articles if you search for "headless wordpress". You can effectively turn off the front end with a minimal theme, e.g. [like this](https://github.com/slushman/headless-theme). I'd guess you can unregister or auth filter all of the endpoints you don't want. Probably easiest to IP restrict the admin site in your web server but I expect it can be done in WordPress too.

Comment: Doesn't this still leaves some default WordPress urls, like author, feed, and some post that seem to be only exist in the DB, that google still can index? Also from what I read about WordPress API, its better to not prevent complete access to it because there are some proccesses that are dependent on it. There seems to be alot of endpoints/url that are vital for WordPress to run. Is this question boils down to trial and error in the end? because if so ill delete it =], thanks for the "headless wordpress", this seems like a good starting point.